# MIPS program counting sentences doesn't execute correctly and I can't find the mistake

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to write a mips program that will count the number of sentences and average number of words, from a standard input.

I think the problem is with the amount of .space I'm declaring because the code it's assembling correctly, however the values are zero for both the number of sentences and average number of words. Also I wanted to know whether .space 256 is the maximum bytes there can be in the input or there must be 256 bytes in the input so that the program can work?

Here's what I got so far:

```
    .data
str_input: .space 256
dot: .asciiz  "."
emptySpace: .asciiz " "
msg1: .asciiz "Number of sentences: "
msg2: .asciiz "\nAverage number of words: "

.text
li $v0, 8       #read string
la $a0, str_input   #address of str_input vo $a0
li $a1, 256     #256 max
la $a2, dot
lb $a2, 0($a2)      
la $a3, emptySpace
lb $a3, 0($a3)      
syscall
addi $t1, $zero, 0  #counter for words
addi $t2, $zero, 0  #counter for sentences

Jal charRead
or $s0, $v0, $zero  #char in $s0
or $t0, $a0, $zero  #$t0 pointer to array 

check: 
lb $t1, 0($t0)      #$t1 current char
beqz $t1, end
beq $t1, $a2, IsDot
beq $t1, $a3, IsEmptySpace
addiu $t0, $t0, 1
j check

IsDot:
addi $t1, $t1, 1

IsEmptySpace:
addi $t2, $t2, 1

charRead:
Li $v0, 12      #read character
Syscall
Jr $ra

end: 
la $a0, msg1        #address of msg1 in $a0
li $v0, 4       #load string in $v0
syscall

add $a0, $t2, $zero
li $v0, 1
syscall         #print number of sentences

addi $t1, $t1, 1    #add the last word
div $t1, $t2        #divide number of words with number of sentences
mflo $t3

la $a0, msg2        #address of msg2
li $v0, 4       #load string in $v0
syscall

add $a0, $t3, $zero
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

Comment: Once you jump to `IsDot` or `IsEmptySpace` you never jump back into the `check` loop. Also, what's the point of the `charRead` function when you never use the result?

Comment: Single step through this and at each instruction verify: (a) the values produced by the last instruction: are as expected?  And, (b) the control flow: is the next instruction what you're expecting it to be?  Part of a program's state is what it is going to do next. When that's wrong, bad things happen.